# Bootstrap 5.0 Validation script. how to exclude hidden fields?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
// Below is bootstrap 5.0 validation code. it select all fields including hidden one. What changes should i make in script to exclude hidden fields for validation.
```

Source : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/

---

Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```